# Why the MOSFET VDSS is measured at 250 µA?

Tags: mosfet, powermosfet

General defintition of the MOSFET VDSS is " BVDSS is usually defined as the drain to source voltage when leakage current is 250uA"

How this number 250 µA came? or What is the significance of this particular number?

Comment: In all likelihood, one or two vendors happened to use this particular current (it is important to state this condition) and it ended up being a *de-facto* value (as has happened a *lot* in electronics).

Comment: It's probably not a coincidence that gate threshold voltage is specified at a drain current of 250 uA as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number isn't significant on its own...VDSS indicates the drain-source voltage that won't damage the part.  As the voltage is increased (based on an enhancement mode device with zero gate-source voltage) it will eventually break down and conduct enough current to damage itself.  250uA was chosen by this manufacturer as a level indicating the beginning of breakdown but not damaging to the device.  Other manufacturers specify it at other currents; for example, [this device](http://cdn.vicorpower.com/documents/datasheets/Picor/ds_PI5101.pdf) is specified at 5mA.

Comment: 360μΩ RDS(on)? Witchcraft!